# Radical Center of 4 circles

Tags: geometry, triangulation

[Radical center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhDSG.png) is described as the center of the unique circle that intersects three given circles at right angles. ([Wikipedia Link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjPt6Xbi-ziAhUJsaQKHRPNBrwQFjAAegQIABAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FRadical_axis&usg=AOvVaw2XbZBLq0LF1q_e4zqhqCOh) ). [This paper](https://orbi.uliege.be/bitstream/2268/89435/1/Pierlot2011ANewThreeObject.pdf) gives a good example to the method.
What I wonder is how to implement this method to 4 circles.
Say we have 4 circles with known origin points $\{(x1,y1) ,(x2,y2),(x3,y3),(x4,y4)\}$ and radius $(r1, r2, r3, r4).$ In this case how can I calculate the radical center of these 4 circles?

**PS**: I couldn't add these tags because of the rep issue. Could the admin add them please : radical-center, radical-lines, power-center

Comment: Why should four circles have a "radical centre"?

Comment: Why not? The radical lines of these 4 circles may be concurrent. Am I thinking wrong?

Comment: So if they are concurrent, just find the radical center of any 3 of them then